# How can i show scroll about canvas with absolute postion

Tags: css, html5-canvas, position

I have double layer canvas with absolute position and z-index. And i want to scroll canvas.

I tried using parent div with autoscroll but not worked 
it showed all canvas area. may be it was z-index problem

Here is my html code.

```html
<div style="overflow:scroll; width:500px; height:500px;">
   <canvas id="canvas1" style="position: absolute; left:10px; top:10px; z-index:0;"></canvas>
   <canvas id="canvas2" style="position: absolute; left:10px; top:10px; z-index:1;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Please suggest any idea. thank you

Comment: You have a typo in `<div stlye="overflow:scroll; width:500px; height:500px;">`, it should be `<div style="overflow:scroll; width:500px; height:500px;">`

Comment: "And i want to control that with scrollbar." What control? Please elaborate.

Comment: i want to use scrollabar for canvas

Answer (score 0):

solved problem.

i used realtive position and top: - (canavas1.height)px

```
<div style="overflow:scroll; width:500px; height:500px;">
   <canvas id="canvas1" style="position: relative; height:100px; z-index:0;"></canvas>
   <canvas id="canvas2" style="position: relative; top:-100px; z-index:1;"></canvas>
</div>
```